# Assign variable if list index out of range python error

Tags: python, indexing, error-handling, fasta, index-error

How to pass a string to a variable if an index error is found? Consider the code:

```
for l1, l2 in zip(open('file1.list'), open ('file2.list')):
  a=fasta1[int(l1)]
  b=fasta2[int(l2)]

  alignments = pairwise2.align.globalxx(a,b)
  top_aln = alignments[0]
  aln_a, aln_b, score, begin, end = top_aln
  print aln_a+'\n'+aln_b
  outfast1 = aln_a
  outfast2 = aln_b
```

A number of these functions must be imported (pairwise2 align), 
but the file.lists are single column text files with one sequence id (text and numbers) per line, that are used to extract from the fasta1 and fasta2 text files.

Basically, I want to `try:` each list command ( `a=fasta1[int(l1)]`) and if there is no error (the id is in range), do as normal (assign variables a and b for that iteration), but if NOT, assign the 'a' variable some placeholder text like 'GGG':

```
for l1, l2 in zip(open('file1.list'), open ('file2.list')):
 try:
  a=fasta1[int(l1)]
 except IndexError,e:
  a="GGG"
 continue

 try:
  b=fasta2[int(l2)]
 except (IndexError):
  b="CCC"
 continue
```

This code doesn't quite work (when integrated with above code), which isn't surprising given my lack of python prowess, but I don't quite know why. I actually get no text output, despite the print calls... Am I thinking about this right? If there is NO error in the index, I just want it to go on and do the pairwise alignment (with the first a and b variables) and then print some text to stdout.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Is the ```continue``` statement in the except suite?

Comment: Do you understand that if [```continue```](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) is executed, everything after it is skipped and the next iteration begins?

Comment: I thought it should be matched with the try/except ? Python doesn't flag that indent structure, but it is not working obv. I want to continue if there is no index error

Comment: No, I didn't. And I don't want that. So, do I not need any end or break to the `try` command?

Comment: Look at - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.

Comment: ... https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Answer (score 2):

Python's [conditional](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (aka ternary) expressions can one-line this for you. They're often criticized for lack of readability, but I think this example reads well enough.

```
a = fasta1[int(l1)] if int(l1) < len(fasta1) else "GGG"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `continue`, because it will skip that iteration of the loop. Consider the following:

```
for l1, l2 in zip(open('file1.list'), open ('file2.list')):
 a = 'GGG'
 b = 'CCC'
 try:
  a = fasta1[int(l1)]
  b = fasta2[int(l2)]
 except IndexError:
  pass
```